# как получить iterator от map по ключу. например: m[1]=1; m[2]=2 .... m[100000]=100000 и как получить iterator m[100000]

Tags: c++, map

как получить iterator от map. например: m[1]=1; m[2]=2 .... m[100000]=100000 и как получить iterator m[100000] на c++. m это map, 100000 это ключ

Comment: Получить по каким входным данным? По порядковому номеру в последовательности? По ключу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос нечетко сформулирован.

- Если речь идет об итераторе для последнего элемента последовательности, то это просто

  ```
  auto it = std::prev(m.end());
  ```
- Если речь идет об итераторе по порядковому номеру в последовательности, то, например

  ```
  auto it = std::next(m.begin(), 100000);
  ```
- Если речь идет об итераторе по ключу map, то

  ```
  auto it = m.find(100000);
  ```

Comment: спасибо. помогли.  речь идет об итераторе по ключу map.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> map = {{1,"one"}, {2,"two"},{3,"three"}};
    auto nx = std::next(map.begin(), 2);
    std::cout<<nx->first<<" "<<nx->second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: спасибо но этот код не работает на gnu c++11 а мне нужно код для gnu c++11

Comment: @luka mosiashvili: Не надо выдумывать. Этот код прекрасно работает на gnu c++11.

Comment: @lukamosiashvili, скомпилируй с флагом -std=c++11